# I have nested key like MainKey-SubKey1-Subkey2-Subkey3 = value

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

`ex: Main Key M1 ,Sub Key s1 ,s2 and s3` My data is like
`M1 s1-s2-s3 =value1` M1-S1-S2 = Value2
``M1-S1 = Value3
`M1 = Value4`

`Output expectations:` If I request with Key M1 all 4 values value1..4 should be returned.
`If I request with Key M1-S1 then 3 Values value1..3 should be returned.` If I request with Key M1-S1-S2 then 2 Values Valuel & Value2 should be returned
I Have check [Redis Hash] (https://redis.io/commands/?group=hash) but it supports at Key and field

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Suggesting you to spend some time in rephrasing the question so that it is understandable to others